# porque sale este error al usar babel en node?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, vscode, babel

Estoy usando node y babel con estas config

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/index.js "
  },
 "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/node": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
```

Al usar npm start me sale este error:

```
[nodemon] starting `babel-node src/index.js`
"babel-node" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
```

Comment: Tienes instaladas todas las dependencias? Es decir... Ya hiciste `npm install`?

Comment: Intenta utilizar los siguientes scripts: `"scripts": {
  "babel-node": "babel-node --presets=env",
  "start": "nodemon --exec npm run babel-node -- ./src/index.js",
  "build": "babel src -d dist"
},`